# How to get a correct simple Spring data JPA query which returns map?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
   Map<id,HelloEntity  > = helloEntityRepository.getval( List<integer> id);
```

I am try to creating getting the data like this:

```
@Query(value="Select (??) FROM HelloEntitytable  WHERE id =:IN(Id)")
    Map<id,HelloEntity  >getmatchingidValues(@Param("Id")List<integer> id);
```

This is fix that for every id have only one entity to map. What is the correct query for above situation?

Where `id` is one parameter in `HelloEntitytable`. Like there are following column in table:

```
generatedid (Primary Key), id (Integer), name (String).
```

Comment: `Map<id`- You have a class called `id`?

Comment: help me guys anyone who can do it so